# detect object place relatively to another object in canvas HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision-detection

I am developing a simple game in `HTML5` and `javascript`. the game is as simple as this:

- the game should instruct the player to put certain objects in certain
  places in the canvas, e.g:  put the apple inside the box or, put the
  apple beside the box.
- When the player drag the object and drop it in any place in the
  canvas
- the game should evaluate his action and decide whether he placed the
  right object in the right place or not.

  **My question is:** how can I test where the user placed an object according to another object? i.e: how can I know that the user put the object beside the box or below the box or even inside the box?

the only ideas that came across my mind are:

- to draw a transparent `Image()` in canvas and use its boundaries as a drop area
- or create a `<div>` in the places that the player should put the object in, and whenever an object collides with this area I should test the user's action. However, I can't create a `<div>` inside a canvas and didn't succeed in creating a transparent `Image()`. any ideas ?

Comment: You would have some sort of coordinate system to place the object right? You can detect mouse positions during the drag & drop to know where the new object is dropped, compare that with the positions of your boxes and you should be able to evaluate the relative position of the apple to the boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used imcg's answer for collision and modified it a little bit to cover the onRight and onLeft cases as following:

```
var overlap = getOverlapArea(shape1.x, shape1.y, shape1.w, shape1.h, shape2.x, shape2.y, shape2.w, shape2.h);
    if(overlap >0)
    {
        console.log("overlapping");
    }
    else {
    var toTheLeft = getOverlapToLeftArea(shape1.x, shape1.y, shape1.w, shape1.h, shape2.x, shape2.y, shape2.w, shape2.h);
        if (toTheLeft > 0) {
        console.log("to the left");
        } 
        else {
                var toTheRight = getOverlapToRightArea(shape1.x, shape1.y, shape1.w, shape1.h, shape2.x, shape2.y, shape2.w, shape2.h);
            if (toTheRight > 0) {
                console.log("to the right");
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("nothing");
            }

    }
```

in the first if statement above, I checked for overlapping just like imcg answered.

In the following function (`getOverlapToLeftArea`) I added `+20 px` to the x assuming that if shape1 is distant from shape2 by more than 20 px then it's considered too far, but if shape1 distant from shape2 by `20px` or less then shape1 is to the left of shape2.

```
function getOverlapToLeftArea(aX, aY, aW, aH, bX, bY, bW, bH) {
    var overlapX = Math.max(0, Math.min(aX + aW + 20, bX + bW) - Math.max(aX + 20 , bX));
    var overlapY = Math.max(0, Math.min(aY + aH, bY + bH) - Math.max(aY, bY));
    return overlapX * overlapY;
}
```

the same concept goes for `getOverlapToLeftArea`except that I subtract `-20 px`from x as following:

```
function getOverlapToRightArea(aX, aY, aW, aH, bX, bY, bW, bH) {
    var overlapX = Math.max(0, Math.min(aX + aW - 20, bX + bW) - Math.max(aX - 20 , bX));
    var overlapY = Math.max(0, Math.min(aY + aH, bY + bH) - Math.max(aY, bY));
    return overlapX * overlapY;
}
```

that worked like charm for me.
and if I would like to check if shape1 is ***above***/***Under*** shape2 I would have to add/subtract `20px` from ***y***

Thank you imcg :) and I hope my answer help you all.

Answer (score 0):

Use the x, y, width and height of each object to check whether they overlap:

```
function getOverlapArea(aX, aY, aW, aH, bX, bY, bW, bH) {
    var overlapX = Math.max(0, Math.min(aX + aW, bX + bW) - Math.max(aX, bX));
    var overlapY = Math.max(0, Math.min(aY + aH, bY + bH) - Math.max(aY, bY));
    return overlapX * overlapY;
}

var apple = { x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100 };
var box = { x: 200, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100 };

var overlap = getOverlapArea(apple.x, apple.y, apple.width, apple.height, box.x, box.y, box.width, box.height);

if(overlap > 0) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: your answer works perfectly in detecting collision between two objects. but what if I want to know whether a is to the left of b for example?

Comment: Simple answer is: isToLeft = a.x < b.x